# Find parent attribute and append to child

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform some xml files and one of the task is to find an attribute in a specified node and append the attribute value for the 
child node.
For example here is the original xml:

```
<ParentNode attribute="someValue">
    <ChildNode other_att="foo">
       <OtherNode />
    </ChildNode>   
</ParentNode>
```

And that's the desired output:

```
<ParentNode attribute="someValue">
    <ChildNode other_att="foo" appended_attribute="someValue">
       <OtherNode />
    </ChildNode>   
</ParentNode>
```

I'm just getting familiar with xslt. Here is what I tried to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ChildNode">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="appended_attribute">
                <xsl:value-of select="'someValue'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it just selected the childnode and append the attribute with hardwired value.

Any advice approciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
    <xsl:template match="ChildNode">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="appended_attribute">
            <xsl:value-of select="'someValue'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

to

```
    <xsl:template match="ChildNode">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="appended_attribute">
            <xsl:value-of select="../@attribute"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Martin Honnen - Very nice. Can you explain the purpose of including ? <//br> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> > `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`

Comment: That code processes attributes and child nodes with matching templates, in that case with the identity transformation template which simply copies attributes and shallow copies elements processing attributes and child nodes recursively with the same approach. Usually people just write one `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>` instead of two `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`.